# Setting object properties selectively

Tags: c#

I have a business object with these properties:

```
Public class Person
{
  prop int ID {get; set;}
  prop string Name {get; set;}
  prop string Address1 {get; set;}
  prop string Address2 {get; set;}
}
```

There is this method

```
Public Void CreateEntity(Person objPerson)
{
 Person newPerson = new Person();
 newPerson.Name = objPerson.Name;
 newPerson.ID = objPerson.ID;
 newPerson.Address1 = objPerson.Address1;
 newPerson.Address2 = objPerson.Address2;

  ...

  // Do some stuff
 }
```

It basically assigns all the properties of objPerson to newPerson.

Is there a way to assign selective properties to newPerson?

Instead of doing one-to-one, can it be done selectively like doing only

```
 newPerson.Address1 = objPerson.Address1;
 newPerson.Address2 = objPerson.Address2;
```

in the method.

I can have an external configuration where the required properties can be defined.
So if that config has only Address1 and Address2, newPerson only gets those two assigned.

Can this be done?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you want correctly, you can use *Object Initializers*:

```
var person = new Person{ ID = 123456, Name = "Foo"};
```

[Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx)

Comment: How do I make it generic? If the properties to be set can be configured and then set only those properties?

Comment: I have edited the question to include a scenario. Thanks for your time and appreciate your help.

Comment: @Codehelp, you need to use `reflection`.

Comment: @godron I have added more code to  better explain the situation I am in. Please look at it. I tried with reflection but I don't know how to assign the properties using it! Any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

With the object initializer:

```
var obj = new Person { ID = 1, Name = "Test" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Add private fields for each of your public properties and use this fields in your public properties, instead of directly using `get; set;`.

Then write your conditions into setters, and only if the conditions are satisfied change the private related private field.

```
private int id;

public int ID {
get
{
    return id;
} 
set
{
    if(someCondition)
       id = value;
}
```

}